# javafx 8 TreeView mouse clicked on the last node of a tree

Tags: javafx, treeview, mouseevent

I have a multi level tree view. It has several tree items. I expand only one level when I load. User can expand one by one by clicking on the arrow of that tree Item. As I keep expanding the last node keeps moving down and goes out of the view port. I scroll down, and click on the arrow. I get the error.

```
    @FXML
    private void createDescendantsTreeView(TreeView<APerson> thisTreeView) {

        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(thisTreeView, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(thisTreeView, 10.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(thisTreeView, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(thisTreeView, 5.0);
        thisTreeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        thisTreeView.setPrefHeight(vBoxHt);

        thisTreeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<APerson>, TreeCell<APerson>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<APerson> call(TreeView<APerson> thisTreeView) {
                return new TreeCell<APerson>() {
                    protected void updateItem(final APerson thisPerson, boolean empty) {

                        super.updateItem(thisPerson, empty);
                        // if the item is not empty and is a root...
                        if (!empty) {
                            setTooltip(thisPerson.getToolTip());
// This will set Context menu for the node
                            if (thisPerson.getFatherID() != 0) {
                                this.setContextMenu(rightContextMenu);
                            }

                            if (thisPerson.getGender().charAt(0) == 'M') {
                                setText(thisPerson.getPersonName() + " [" + thisPerson.getPersonID() + "]");
                                ImageView maleIcon = new ImageView(maleImage);
                                setGraphic(maleIcon);
                                String cellStyle = "    -fx-font-size: 16;\n" + "    -fx-font-family: \"Times New Roman\";\n" + "-fx-text-fill: blue;";
                                setStyle(cellStyle);
                            } else {
                                setText(thisPerson.getPersonName() + " [" + thisPerson.getPersonID() + "]");
                                ImageView femaleIcon = new ImageView(femaleImage);
                                setGraphic(femaleIcon);
                                String cellStyle = "    -fx-font-size: 16;\n" + "    -fx-font-family: \"Times New Roman\";\n" + "-fx-text-fill: red;";
                                setStyle(cellStyle);
                            }
                        } else {
                            this.setText(null);
                            this.setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        childrenTreeView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                Node node = mouseEvent.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
                    System.out.println("Node click: " + node.toString());

                if (node instanceof Text || (node instanceof TreeCell && ((TreeCell) node).getText() != null)) {
                    TreeItem TreeItemAtLocation = new TreeItem();
                    TreeItemAtLocation = childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    System.out.println("Child Tree - clicked on : " + TreeItemAtLocation.getValue().toString());
                    String name = childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue().toString();
                    APerson tmp = childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue();
                    if (TreeItemAtLocation.getParent() == null) {
                        removePicture.setDisable(true);
                    } else {
                        removePicture.setDisable(false);
                    }
                    if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
                        if (TreeItemAtLocation != null) {
                            if (childrenTreeView.getRoot() == TreeItemAtLocation) {
                                addPerson.setDisable(false);
                                deletePerson.setDisable(true);
                                deleteThisFamily.setDisable(true);
                                modifyPerson.setDisable(true);
                                viewPerson.setDisable(true);
                            } else {
                                addPerson.setDisable(false);
                                deletePerson.setDisable(false);
                                if (TreeItemAtLocation.isLeaf()) {
                                    deleteThisFamily.setDisable(true);
                                } else {
                                    deleteThisFamily.setDisable(false);
                                }
                                modifyPerson.setDisable(false);
                                viewPerson.setDisable(false);
                            }
                            rightContextMenu.show(myMainApp.getMainStage());
                        } else {
                            rightContextMenu.hide();
                        }
                    } else {
                        rightContextMenu.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This Image shows the screen and the I am talking about the tree in the right hand side. As I keep expanding the nodes, the last Tree Item scrolls down and not visible in this image. I scroll down to see that Tree Item and when I click on the arrow for that Tree item I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
Node click: MainWindowController$5$1@1051fb6[styleClass=cell indexed-cell tree-cell]'Daughter  [363]'
    at familytreev01.MainWindowController$6.handle(MainWindowController.java:510)
    at familytreev01.MainWindowController$6.handle(MainWindowController.java:501)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Node click: MainWindowController$5$1@36f8bc[styleClass=cell indexed-cell tree-cell]'null'
Node click: StackPane@b679e7[styleClass=tree-disclosure-node]
Deleting directory D:\JavaFXPrograms\FamilyTreeV01\dist\run8821460
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 minutes 1 second)
```

However, if I select that Tree Item first and then click on that arrow, I don't get that error. It expands without any hassles. Right click on that Tree Item also works fine.

The error comes in line where I assign the value to a class variable.
childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue();

Why would this happen only to the last node ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not register the mouse handler on the cell (which you can do in your cell factory), instead of on the tree? Then you don't need all that ugly code to figure out which cell was clicked.

Comment: Thanks James it worked.